# NSFetchRequest ReturnsDistinctResults gives empty results

Tags: swift

I am trying to filter out the duplicate items in a result from a fetchRequest. I use the following code:

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastupdate", ascending: false)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Details")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
            fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [ "orig_id" ]
            fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType
            fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true


        let company_temp = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        let company = company_temp as! [Details]
        for t in company {
            let id = t.orig_id
            print(id)
            self.myarray.append("\(id)")

        }
```

When I comment out these 3 lines:

```
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [ "orig_id" ]
            fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType
            fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true
```

I get 8 items in my array. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: and if you print `company_temp` what do you get? and at the moment do you get a crash?

Comment: It's empty, just `[]`

Answer (score 2):

Did you save your context?
I had the same problem. When you have unsaved changes, the NSDictionaryResultType does not reflect the current state of the persistent store. See [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFetchRequest/includesPendingChanges) about the `includesPendingChanges:` method.

So a simple `context.save()` before your code might fixes your problem.

Another problem is that this line will crash: `let company = company_temp as! [Details]` since you'll get a `Dictionary` back. Not a list of `NSManagedObject`.